# Swagger 2 & spring MVC - ignore the war context path

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger

I am using swagger 2 with spring mvc.

The war file is web-app.war and Swagger base URL is shown as `/web-app/rest/api`

I would like to remove the war context path so the api call can be made as

`example.com/rest/api` and **not** `example.com/web-app/rest/api`

SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        // @formatter:off
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .pathMapping("/")
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }


    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
         return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Rest API")
                 .description("Describes the restful interface")
                 .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `/web-app` is your context root (you can change it in your IDE, plenty of tutorials online on how to do that) -- then there is no way you can place an element of your project outside that.

To achieve what you want, you could set the context root to `/` and then prefix your REST services with `web-app`. This keeps the same REST path, but places the Swagger API at `/rest/api`.

**EDIT**

If you believe Springfox has wrongly determined your base path, you can add a `PathProvider` to the `Docket` definition:

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
    /*other options*/
    .pathProvider(new PathProvider(){

        String getApplicationBasePath(){
            return "/";
        }
        /*implement other methods or extend RelativePathProvider or Absolute PathProvider instead */
    }
```

Comment: not sure what do u meant by changing it in IDE? The issue is only when swagger makes a request (Try it out!) it is adding /web-app to the URL.
if I directly access the URL is browser without /web-app everything works.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this issue, need to change the host property of the Docket. Otherwise, the basePath will be determined based on the request url (as per [Swagger2Controller](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/blob/2.8.0/springfox-swagger2/src/main/java/springfox/documentation/swagger2/web/Swagger2Controller.java#L85) and [how to change base path for swagger](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1443))

```
   @Bean
    public Docket api(ServletContext servletContext) throws LoadPropertiesException {
        String host = "example.com";
        String applicationBasePath = null;
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
          .groupName("My API").host(host).pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {
              @Override
              public String getApplicationBasePath() {
                  return applicationBasePath;
              }
          })
          .select()
          .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot"))) .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.cloud"))) .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc")))                       
          .build()
          .apiInfo(apiInfo());                                         
    }
```